# Do OS providers make special / custom made OS for docker?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am trying to understand Docker and its related core concepts, I came to know that there is concept of `images` which forms the basis of `container` where applications run isolated.

I also came to know that we can download the official images from docker hub, `https://hub.docker.com` , part of screen shot below:

[image]

## My question is:

Do respective company create special/custom made OS (the minimal, for example we can see ubuntu image) for docker? If so, what benefit these companies get in creating these custom made images for docker?

Comment: Assuming Ubuntu, Apache and MySQL are interested in making their software easy to use for Docker users, providing an official image would help with that. Just like providing offical DEB or RPM or DMG or VMI does for the users of those formats. But "official" here may mean "provided by Docker (the company)" not necessarily "provided by upstream vendor". In that case, the motivation is to make Docker easier to use for people looking for Ubuntu/httpd/mysql .

Answer (score 0):

One could call them *custom images*, however, they are just base bare images which are to be used as a starting point for your application.

They are mostly built by people who works at Docker and they are trying to ensure some guarantee of quality.

They are stripped of unnecessary packages in order to keep the image size to a minimum.

To find out more you could read this Docker documentation [page](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_repos/#should-i-use-official-repositories) or this [blog post](http://container-solutions.com/docker-official-images-good-bad-ugly/).